# Exception Initialisation when running spark application on cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark, guava, sbt-assembly

I'm trying to run my spark application on my cluster who is composed of two slaves servers and one master server. When I'm running my main from the .jar that I made with sbt-assembly, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<clinit>(Cluster.java:68)
at com.outworkers.phantom.connectors.DefaultSessionProvider.<init>
(DefaultSessionProvider.scala:41)
at com.outworkers.phantom.connectors.CassandraConnection.provider$lzycompute(CassandraConnection.scala:41)
at com.outworkers.phantom.connectors.CassandraConnection.provider(CassandraConnection.scala:41)
at com.outworkers.phantom.connectors.CassandraConnection.session$lzycompute(CassandraConnection.scala:52)
at com.outworkers.phantom.connectors.CassandraConnection.session(CassandraConnection.scala:52)
at com.outworkers.phantom.database.Database.session$lzycompute(Database.scala:38)
at com.outworkers.phantom.database.Database.session(Database.scala:38)
at com.outworkers.phantom.database.Database.createAsync(Database.scala:85)
at com.outworkers.phantom.database.Database.create(Database.scala:75)
at Main$.main(Mainlearning.scala:20)
at Main.main(Mainlearning.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError: Detected 
incompatible version of Guava in the classpath. You need 16.0.1 or higher.
at
```

com.datastax.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility.selectImplementation(GuavaCompatibility.java:138)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility.
   (GuavaCompatibility.java:52)

thank you.

Edit : While searching for a response on Internet. I found that the version of guava in spark/jars was 14.0 and the version of guava in my uber jar is 19.0. The following error is asking for a version of guava superior at 16.0. My question is how can I force spark to choose the guava librairy from my uber jar and not the version located in the jar of the spark directory.

Comment: What versions of Cassandra driver and Guava do you use? Could you post relevant fragments of `mvn dependency:tree` output?

Comment: I'm using Cassandra 3.11 and I can't tell you the version of guava because this is spark who use it and not me. I'm using sbt and not maven. Do you want to see the output of the command inspect ? thank you for trying to help

Comment: @Xaerxess I look into my assembly jar and I'm using guava-19.0

Comment: Message _Detected 
incompatible version of Guava in the classpath. You need 16.0.1 or higher._ suggests you have another version of Guava in classpath. If you have maven project, post output from `mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true`.

Comment: This is the output from my uber jar when I'm using assembly :

 [info] Including from cache: guava-19.0.jar

 
and in my directory spark : the version of guava is 14.0. I'm using spark 2.1.0

Comment: That's the problem you need to fix - you have Guava 14.0 from Spark and Cassandra driver works with Guava 16.0.1+.